# Haskell: error taking in list of tuples -> outputting list of tuples

Tags: haskell

So I'm having a blast working through a Haskell tutorial... one challenge is to:

"Write a Lambda expression and map, to take a list of tuples and produce a list of tuples. The list contains the lengths of two sides of right triangles, a and b.  Produce a list that contains the length of all three sides, where the third side is c, found with the Pythagorean Theorem" (of course).

With example input/output like:

```
[(3,4),(5,16),(9.4,2)]
== [(3.0,4.0,5.0),(5.0,16.0,16.76305461424021),(9.4,2,9.610411021387172)]
```

So I did some practice stuff first, like just getting the correct answer to the Pythagorean theorem, then taking in a tuple but outputting as usual, then taking in and putting out a tuple -- that all worked, eventually getting to this Lambda expression:

```
pythagLambdaTupleInOut = (\(a,b) -> (a,b,(sqrt $ a^2 + b^2)))
```

It compiled and produced this:

```
ghci > pythagLambdaTupleInOut (3,4)
(3.0,4.0,5.0)
```

So it works...
So then I tried:

```
pythagLambdaListTupleInOut = (\[(a,b)] -> [(a,b,(sqrt $ a^2 + b^2))])
```

It compiles, but this happens when I try to use it:

```
ghci > pythagLambdaListTupleInOut [(3,4),(5,16)]
*** Exception: six.hs:1376:31-68: Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda
```

Any clues what I'm missing?  Is it something with `map`?  I wasn't sure how to work `map` in there, based on the examples in the tutorial...

Haskell, btw, is fascinating and so cool!

Comment: `[(a,b)]` only matches a single-element list. In order to work through a list of any length, you need a different approach. Yes it is something with `map`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function you looking for is

```
pythagLambdaListTupleInOut = map (\(a,b) -> (a,b,(sqrt $ a^2 + b^2)))
```

your version fails because `[(a,b)]` pattern mean list with single element, and that element is tuple. When you pass list with two tuple haskell unable to pattern match.

Comment: You need parentheses around the lambda, or `$` between it and `map`, unless you enable the `BlockArguments` extension (as of GHC 8.6.1), which allows lambdas and `do` blocks directly as function arguments

Comment: Okay, so now I feel kinda like a dork.  That is so obvious now that I see it... I'd even done something similar in another exercise!  I must have been up too late having fun.  Thank you @talex

Comment: @Stormy don't worry about it. Every one who study new things have that felling from time to time.